# Objects/elements disappear when online publishing an Adobe InDesign interactive PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, adobe-acrobat, publishing

When I '*publish online*' my Adobe InDesign interactive PDF, some of the elements and objects don't show.

For example, little things such as some of the shadow effects dissapear when exported this way.

Any ideas why/how to rectify?

Cheers,
R

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the InDesign file and/or PDF file. Does the interactive PDF show correctly when viewing in Adobe Reader? If you copy the shadow effect to a new document and export that PDF, does it still not show?

Comment: Hi @AndrewH. 1. Yes, if I export as a normal (offline) interactive PDF then all the objects and features are there, it's only when I try to publish online that things disappear. 2. I have just tried copy the effect to a new document and export it, but it has the same issue. Something wrong with the object itself?